# Obtener las RPM del ventilador de mi pc con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Intento obtener datos del Hardware y `psutil.sensors_fans()` solo funciona en Linux. ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener la velocidad del ventilador con Python en Windows?

Comment: ¿Has probado con [`wmi`](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/)?